# React-Router V6 Routes Array Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router V6 and I'm getting a typescript error on my nested children routes. I'm new to Typescript so I might be doing this completely wrong. Can someone please help me out.

**Error message**

```
Type '{ path: string; element: JSX.Element; }' is not assignable to type 'ReactChildren'.
```

Path: `Routes`

```
const routes: { path: string, element: React.ReactChild, children: React.ReactChildren[] }[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <FormPage title="Dashboard" />,
    children: [
      { path: 'test-page', element: <p>Test page</p> }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to achieve, it this a config for `useRoutes` [hook](http://%20https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/api#useroutes)?

If yes, than the type is `RouteObject[]` and element is `ReactNode`, see the definitions below.

```js
/**
 * A route object represents a logical route, with (optionally) its child
 * routes organized in a tree-like structure.
 */
export interface RouteObject {
    caseSensitive?: boolean;
    children?: RouteObject[];
    element?: React.ReactNode;
    index?: boolean;
    path?: string;
}

/**
 * Returns the element of the route that matched the current location, prepared
 * with the correct context to render the remainder of the route tree. Route
 * elements in the tree must render an <Outlet> to render their child route's
 * element.
 *
 * @see https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useroutes
 */
export declare function useRoutes(routes: RouteObject[], locationArg?: Partial<Location> | string): React.ReactElement | null;
```